# Json parsing using rapidJson in c++ giving Error

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

The given string Format is given Below:

```
"{"success":"yes","error":"","message":"","arguments":"[{\"assetId\":\"7384\",\"assetSerialNo\":\"Base Map\",\"assetDescription\":\"\",\"assetVersion\":\"\",\"assetIsMovable\":\"f\",\"assetType\":\"Layer\",\"assetModel\":\"Tile\",\"parentId\":\"7362\",\"assetIsTrackable\":\"f\",\"assetInheritsRegion\":\"f\",\"assetRegion\":\"\",\"typeId\":\"15\"}]"}"
```

Object within an array and that array is within an Object. But when I parse this string :

document.h is included

> Document obj;
>   obj.Parse<0>(json);

It give an error :

> document.h:1718:22: note: template rapidjson::GenericDocument& rapidjson::GenericDocument::Parse(const Ch*) [with unsigned int parseFlags = parseFlags, SourceEncoding = SourceEncoding, Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>, Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>, StackAllocator = rapidjson::CrtAllocator, rapidjson::GenericDocument = rapidjson::GenericDocument >, rapidjson::GenericDocument::Ch = char]
>   document.h:1729:22: note: template rapidjson::GenericDocument& rapidjson::GenericDocument::Parse(const Ch*) [with unsigned int parseFlags = parseFlags, Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>, Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>, StackAllocator = rapidjson::CrtAllocator, rapidjson::GenericDocument = rapidjson::GenericDocument >, rapidjson::GenericDocument::Ch = char]

How I json Decode that format and retrieve assetId .The main object does not have \"\" around string as As this format is returned from an api ?

Comment: You're missing _loads_ of the error message. Specifically, the part which actually says what's wrong. You only posted two "notes".

Comment: There is something wrong with your json string. It's not even escaped properly for starters.

Comment: Aren't header only libraries fun!!

Comment: Have you tried compiling the examples and see if they works?

Comment: yes I compile one of the example its work.As I  am new in c++ how I extract useful data from the above String ie assetId in c++ .I means which buildIn c++ funcation help to extract data.

Answer (score 0):

According https://jsonlint.com/ a valid JSON would be more like this:

"{"success":"yes","error":"","message":"","arguments":" [{"assetId":"7384","assetSerialNo":"Base Map","assetDescription":"","assetVersion":"","assetIsMovable":"f","assetType":"Layer","assetModel":"Tile","parentId":"7362","assetIsTrackable":"f","assetInheritsRegion":"f","assetRegion":"","typeId":"15"}]}"